# Routing / Distance Matrix Strategies

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently developing an application which makes use of the free Google Maps API (not Google Maps for Business API!).

For this I am making use of:
1. geocoding
2. map display
2. distance matrix
3. routing services
(find infos here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/)

As usage limitations apply (checkout developers.google.com/maps/licensing ), google proposes client-side geocoding for 1. as described here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

As 2.,3. and 4. request are quite limited too I would like to understand if the "go client-side" strategy also applies to these services?

If yes our problems would be solved!

Unfortunately I can't find any information on the google web site on how exactly these limitations are counted (e.g. per IP address would mean client-side is fine)

If not we would quickly need to find a different provider as the business license for these services currently exceeds our budget.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've also evaluated this service recently. There is a mention in the documentation link that the quota is purely per IP address.

Comment: You could take a look at what requests you actually 'need' to make from google. Geolocation for example 'can' be done with them or other methods. You could even make it dynamic, if you don't get a response from the other methods then fallback to google option automatically. It may help to reduce your calls.

Comment: supsectus, it would be great if you coud provide me with reference as I wasn't able to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: @Rafe Thanks for the hint. I am using all 4 services for different use cases and will surely run over all of them. Fallbacks are implemented but I really require clarity on the usage limitation issue I tried to describe.

Comment: I think clarity is beyond anyones abaility to give at the moment (including from Google themselves). As they state on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions the only place the word 'limit' appears is in the transit options (which event they don't know how to tally yet it seems) and the main link to useage limits of 25,000 map loads per day. Your guess is as good as mine.